# Сильная привязанность к объекту в аргументах метода

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня написан метод, который в качестве аргумента принимает экземпляр multiprocessing.Event.
Так-как я знаю, что неправильно сильно привязываться к объектам(наглядный пример это объект request в Django), то хотелось бы узнать, как поступить.

Метод:

```
def some_method(self, end_flag: 'Event'):
   # единственное взаимодействие этого метода с объектом Event - вызов Event.is_set()
```

Мне пришла в голову мысль: передавать вместо объекта метод is_set и вызывать его. Результат по идее должен быть таким же, но код становится сложнее. А из дзена пайтона понятно, что простое лучше, чем сложное.

Comment: `простое лучше, чем сложное.` - зачем вообще передавать что-то, просто выполняйте работу внутри. Если надо регулировать вызов Event(когда он нужен/не нужен), то можно добавить `bool` аргумент.

Comment: у меня код этого метода выполняется в потоке/процессе (target). Не понял что имелось ввиду под "просто выполняйте работу внутри". Когда приложение закрывается, то процессам и потокам нужно так же завершится, а не продолжать забирать объекты из очереди. Есть вариант запушить в очередь None или 'STOP' и после изъятия проверять на эти значения, но я решил воспользоваться event. Event прокидывается в метод и метод работает до тех пор, пока он не установлен(while not event.is_set()).

Comment: я бы с радостью использовал bool аргумент. Что-то вроде is_runnable = True и модифицируется он на верхнем уровне(когда приложение завершается флаг становится False) и в процессах/потоках цикл выглядит следующим образом: while is_runnable. Но будет ли булевое значение работать корректно?